# Aligning icons to the top of a Seekbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-seekbar

I have a `Seekbar` with a `LinearLayout` of icons above it. I'm using `LinearLayout` `weightsum` and `weight` to align each one, however they are still not quite aligned.

[image]

Is there a way to align them?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/test_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_black_trashcan_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_black_trashcan_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_black_trashcan_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_black_trashcan_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_black_trashcan_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="4"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:thumb="@drawable/ic_black_navigation_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/test_layout"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Edit:**

I am aware that you can use

```
android:paddingStart="-16dp"
android:paddingEnd="-16dp"
```

to align them but I rather not prefer to use a set padding, because this causes readjusting the padding when you add another item.

e.g changing icons to 6, need to change weightsum to 6, and also need to set padding to `-14dp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard maintain this with `LinearLayout`, so I used `ConstraintLayout` instead, and using the `Guidelines` to divide the width into 4 equal portions, then you can align the images to these guidelines.. This will be maintainable accross different device widths and screen orientation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/test_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_black_trashcan_24dp" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_black_trashcan_24dp" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_black_trashcan_24dp" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_black_trashcan_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_black_trashcan_24dp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="4"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:thumb="@drawable/ic_black_navigation_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/test_layout"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result:**

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape

[image]